# psql major version 10, server major version 16. Some psql features might not work

Tags: postgresql, rocky-os

Remote server is running on Rocky Linux 8.9 (Green Obsidian). It had PostgreSQL 10 previously installed. This version lacks features essential to my application such as generated columns.

I uninstalled v 10 using rpm, went to the official PostgreSQL repository, and downloaded and installed version 16, which appeared to go successfully. But I get this message.

```
sql: /usr/pgsql-16/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql (10.23, server 16.2)
WARNING: psql major version 10, server major version 16.
         Some psql features might not work.
```

I don't know the implications of this.

I would like to remove all remnants of v 10 but I don't have permission for the Linux command autoremove. I want to know if this is going to be a problem down the line. Perhaps remove the operating system and install Ubuntu, which I know fully supports PostgreSQL 16

Comment: 1) What command are you running which gives this message? 2) How did you uninstall Postgres 10? 3) What does `which psql` say?

Comment: "*I don't have permission for the Linux command autoremove*" but you do have permission to wipe the machine? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

There's mismatch between the psql client and PostgreSQL server versions. Your psql client is still at version 10, while your PostgreSQL server is at version 16.

Ensure that your psql client is also upgraded to version 16. You might need to uninstall the old psql client version and install the new one. You can do this using the yum or dnf package manager with the following commands:

```
sudo yum remove postgresql10
sudo yum install postgresql16
```

or

```
sudo dnf remove postgresql10
sudo dnf install postgresql16
```

I don't know if those are the actual package names for postgresql10 and postgresql16.

As for removing all remnants of PostgreSQL 10, if you do this be careful with this step as it will delete all your databases and tables.

You can use commands like these:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/10/
sudo rm -rf /var/log/postgresql/
sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/
```

And as for switching to Ubuntu, both Ubuntu and Rocky Linux support PostgreSQL 16. The choice between them should be based on your personal preference and the specific requirements of your project.

If you’re comfortable with Rocky Linux and it meets your needs, why switch?

Answer (score 1):

The message is telling you your PostgreSQL server is v16, but your `psql` client is v10.

Rocky (and most distros) splits PostgreSQL into several packages. Relevant here, [`postgresql`](https://rockylinux.pkgs.org/8/rockylinux-appstream-x86_64/postgresql-10.23-4.module+el8.9.0+1734+74bd286c.x86_64.rpm.html) contains the client code like `psql`. [`postgresql-server`](https://rockylinux.pkgs.org/8/rockylinux-appstream-x86_64/postgresql-server-10.23-4.module+el8.9.0+1734+74bd286c.x86_64.rpm.html) contains the server. This split lets you install the relatively small client to contact remote servers without the large server.

You likely only upgraded the server. You also should upgrade the client package.

You do not need to wipe the machine.

Answer (score 0):

To all - thanks for your comments. I don't have permission to remove the OS, but can instruct the IT department to do so. I understand there's a mismatch between client app and server.
While Rocky Linux supports Postgres 16, it only supports PostGIS for 14, and I need that.

Comment: Please use comments for comments and answers for anwers. This should have been a comment on the correct answer above.